AWS Redshift spectrum not able to return data for external table where data type timestamp
I'm trying to query data through Redshift Spectrum using an external schema from the Glue catalog but encountering an issue with a column that has a timestamp data type. When I run the query SELECT * FROM external_schema.table, all columns return data except for the report_date column, which is defined as a timestamp in Glue. In this case, it returns null.
In the Redshift Spectrum external schema, the column is defined as timestamp(0). I've tried converting it to timestamp, date, or varchar, but it always returns null. I've verified that the dataset does not contain any null values for this column; all rows have valid values. I can query the data through Athena without any issues, and I get values for the timestamp.
I suspect the issue is with Redshift Spectrum not reading the data type correctly. Is there anything I can do on the Redshift query side, such as casting or converting to a different data type, or does the Glue definition need to be modified?
I expect to be able to query the data through Redshift and see the data as I can through Athena.

Finding it's a data issue and that while Glue is defining the column as a timestamp and Athena can query it the structure of the data won't allow Redshift to read it. If the data is converted as a 'date' in Glue it comes through to Redshift without issue.
